# Cleanup function with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a project with an API call, and so far I've been able to pass the static data(for know I'll keep it hard coded) and then console.log the data provided by the static data, but I can't store it in my state, I can just console.log it and I dont know why. The following error happens in my console:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Here's the code, I think you guys will see what I'm doing in a better way:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import TopList from "./components/TopList";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: [23251319, 23251742, 23251158, 2423431],
    results: []
  });

  const fetcher = id => {
    fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setState({
          results: data
        });
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TopList data={state.data} fetcher={fetcher} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";

import Top from "./Top";

function TopList({ data, fetcher }) {
  const mapped = data.map(item => (
    <Top fetcher={fetcher} id={item} key={item} />
  ));

  return <div>{mapped}</div>;
}

export default TopList;
```

```
import React from "react";

function Top({ id, fetcher }) {
  fetcher(id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello from top</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Top;
```

Comment: just a hint for better practise: NEVER let a promise uncatched.

Comment: There are a few problems, but sadly I have to run and can't address them all. Here's the **in**complete answer that only addresses a couple of them: https://pastebin.com/FHjDbmnj

Answer (score 0):

You should be fetching the data after the component has mounted inside a `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method or since you are using functional components you can use the `useEffect()` hook.

Secondly you are prop drilling the fetcher to the Top component for no reason.
If the Top component fetches the data, it should be responsible for calling the fetcher inside a `useEffect()` hook.

For example

in your app component

```
export default function App() {
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([23251319, 23251742, 23251158, 2423431]);

  return (
    <div>
      <TopList idArray={ids}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

in TopList

```
 function TopList({ idArray }) {

  return (
      <div>
      {
        idArray.map((id) => (<Top id={id} key={id}/>))
      }
      </div>;
 }
```

In Top Component

```
function Top({ id }) {

  const [state, setState] = useState({results: null, error: undefined})

  useEffect(() => {
   const fetcher = id => {
    fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        // if fetch success
        setState({
          results: data,
          error: undefined
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // if error set results to null and error to the error that happened
        // during fetch
        setState({results: null, error: error})
      });
  };

  // finally call the fetcher with the id
  fetcher(id);

  }, [id])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello from top</h1>
      <pre>{state.results && JSON.stringify(state.results, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```